# rivers with elastic search with relational data

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

Consider the following sql schema:

[image]

Where Table_2 and Table_1 have a many to many relation

now I'm trying to create an elastic search river that will pull in all the data from table_2 but I want the rows from table_1 as well and not just the id's.

Here is what I believe will be my sql:

```
select t2.*, t1.Name from [Table_2] t2
join [Table_3] t3 on t2.ID = t3.table_2
join [Table_1] t1 on t1.ID = t3.table_1
```

Now after doing this I have noticed that I get duplicate rows IE for each relationship in Table_3 I will get one row, I understand why this is but what I want is one entry for Table_2 that has an entry for table one.

This is what I'm getting in elastic now

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test_relation",
                "_type": "relation",
                "_id": "AUpUGlvaRCP4Gzd2p3K4",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "Name": [
                        "table_2test",
                        "Test1"
                    ],
                    "ID": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test_relation",
                "_type": "relation",
                "_id": "AUpUGlvaRCP4Gzd2p3K5",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "Name": [
                        "table_2test",
                        "Test2"
                    ],
                    "ID": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But instead I want it to look like:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test_relation",
                "_type": "relation",
                "_id": "AUpUGlvaRCP4Gzd2p3K4",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "Name": [
                        "table_2test",
                    ],
                    Table_1 :[
                        {"Name": "Test1", "ID": "1"},
                        {"Name": "Test2", "ID": "2"}
                    ]
                    "ID": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I was hoping to get away with using an elasticsearch [river](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/) for sql but I'm not sure if it allows for this kind of query.

Comment: I had several problems with the JDBC river a few years back.  I ended up writing my own.  I used Mybatis to handle the complex result mapping.

Comment: not the answer I was hoping for but expected :(.

Comment: It's not too bad,  you can start with the source of the SQL River.  Let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: @AndyPryor out of curiosity what problems did you run into?

Comment: @dbames -  same as you.  It wasn't handling the complex result maps.  Building single json objects with 1:many lists.  This was 2 years ago,  so maybe it's been improved since then.